# Transfering data from Postgresql to Mysql (From RoR Database into Wordpress Database) from different hosts

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, postgresql

here I come with this problem.

Here we have this host with a full system written in RoR with a considerable amount of data of users into a Postgresql database.

Then, in a separate local host, we have a wordpress page that runs certain applications powered with buddypress plugin (allows custom fields) and of course uses a MySQL database.

What do I need is: to transfer the user data from the Postgresql database into the MySQL one. I'm aware that is possible to create users in Wordpress by inserting data into the database, but I need the query to transfer the same user data from the first database.

I have been thinking in a cronjob with php. (Just unsure how to do the query when they are two different hosts and having to use mysql_connect and pg_connect).

I've created a view in postgresql with the data I need to migrate.

I've also been suggested to try out "Navicat", but unsure if it can do what I exactly need to do.

What would be the way to go? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you can access both the databases, you can write two classes , one derived from `mysql` and other from `postgres`

Ex:

```
#config/database.yml
development: &DEV
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  database: postgresql_db
  username: 
  password: 

wordpress: &WORDPRESS
  adapter: mysql2
  host: localhost
  username: 
  password: 
  database: wordpress
wordpress_development:
  <<: *DEV
```

and you may have a base class for wordpress

```
class WordpressBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  WordpressRecord.establish_connection({
    adapter:  "mysql2",
    host:     ENV['MYSQL_HOST'],
    username: ENV['MYSQL_USER'],
    password: ENV['MYSQL_PASS'],
    database: ENV['MYSQL_DB']
  })

  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

and now you can use normal active record to migrate data

Ex:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  # connects to your postgres
end

class B < WordpressBase
  # connects to your mysql
end
```